# Solve the given integral - I can't find a mistake in my calculations

Tags: calculus, integration

Solve the integral $$\int\sqrt[]{\frac{e^x-1}{e^x+1}}$$

Firstly I distributed it by multiplying with $\frac{\sqrt{e^x-1}}{\sqrt{e^x-1}}$

Then I got $$\int \frac{e^x-1}{\sqrt{e^{2x}-1}}$$

so I split the integral in two:

$$\int \frac{e^{x}}{\sqrt{e^{2x}-1}}-\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{2x}-1}}$$

By solving the first one I got the result: $$\ln(\sqrt{e^{2x}-1}+e^{x})$$ (this part is correct according to various online calculators)

and by solving the second one I got:
$$-\arctan(\sqrt{e^{2x}-1})$$  - this seems to be wrong, according to those online calculators the result is supposed to be $$-\arcsin(e^{-x})$$ (plus the result of the first integral of course $+c$)

Is my arctg and their arcsin algebraically equivalent in any universe?

Comment: No. Multiply numerator and denominator by $e^{-x}$.

Comment: Checking whether an answer to an indefinite integral is correct is much easier than actually integrating: just take the derivative of your function and see if you get the integrand!

Comment: Are you sure both the arctan and the arcsin both have minus signs? Was your answer $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{2x}-1}}dx $$ equal to $+\arctan(\sqrt{e^{2x}-1})$ or $-\arctan(\sqrt{e^{2x}-1})$?

Comment: this integral (individually) is supposed to have a plus sign. When you put those two terms together, the arctan should have a minus sign though (same applies to the arcsin) since we split the integral in two integrals and the second one has a minus sign.

Comment: there are other methods here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c28xYBtW2Es and https://www.quora.com/How-does-one-integrate-e-x-1-e-x-1

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/641656/732917) answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, differentiating both terms and see whether you get the same result is less ambiguous and usually easier.

However, I think you should get $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{2x}-1}}dx = \arctan(\sqrt{e^{2x}-1}),$$ without the minus sign (maybe this was a typo or the minus sign you wrote is the one from in front of the integral in the original problem).

It is true that $\arctan(\sqrt{e^{2x}-1})$ (without the minus) is an equivalent answer to $\arcsin(e^{-x})$, in that they differ by a constant.

Draw a right triangle with angles $\pi/2,\theta,\pi/2-\theta$.  Label the side adjacent to the angle $\theta$ with $A>0$ and label the hypotenuse with $B>A$. Then the side opposite $\theta$ has length $\sqrt{B^2-A^2}$.

Then $$\sin(\pi/2-\theta)=\cos(\theta)=A/B$$ and $$\tan(\theta)=\frac{\sqrt{B^2-A^2}}{A}.$$  Therefore $$\arcsin(A/B)=\pi/2-\theta=\pi/2-\arctan\Bigl(\frac{\sqrt{B^2-A^2}}{A}\Bigr)$$ and $-\arcsin(A/B)$, $\arctan\Bigl(\frac{\sqrt{B^2-A^2}}{A}\Bigr)$ differ by a constant.  In order to get the result in this case, apply this with $B=e^x$ and $A=1$. To be careful, that only works for $x>0$, otherwise we don't have $e^x=B>a$. But in the case $x<0$, we can use $B=1$ and $A=e^{-x}$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way: note that $$\int \sqrt{\tanh x}dx 
=\frac {1}2 \ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{\tanh(x)}+1}{\sqrt{\tanh(x)}-1}\right)-\arctan(\sqrt{\tanh(x)})$$ and apply $$\frac{e^x-1}{e^x+1}\cdot\frac{e^{-\frac x2}}{e^{-\frac x2}}=\tanh\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$